# ManagedCuda: ErrorIllegalAddress: While executing a kernel, the device encountered a load or store instruction on an invalid memory address

Tags: cuda

I am using Managed Cuda 6.5. The graphic card is GTX 770 (Compute capability 3.0).
I am having problem to run my program on platform target X64 but I do not have any problem with X86. 
I am successfully allocating memory on device using for example the following code

`CudaDeviceVariable<double> d_input = new CudaDeviceVariable<double>(input.Length)`.
`CudaDeviceVariable<double> d_output = new CudaDeviceVariable<double>(output.Length)`.

But when it comes to run the kernel such as

```
inToLSTM.BlockDimensions = threadsPerBlock;
inToLSTM.GridDimensions = numberofBlock;
inToLSTM.Run(d_input.DevicePointer,d_output.DevicePointer);
```

it will give me the following error:

"*ErrorIllegalAddress: While executing a kernel, the device encountered a load or store instruction on an invalid memory address.
The context cannot be used, so it must be destroyed (and a new one should be created)*."

The kernel looks like this:

```
__global__ void InToLSTM(double *input,double* output)
{
     int idx=threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    __shared__ double sharedvar[1024];
    sharedvar[threadIdx.x]=input[threadIdx.x];


    __syncthreads();
    if( 0 == threadIdx.x ) 
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < blockDim.x; i++ )
        {
            sum += sharedvar[i];
        }
        output[blockIdx.x]=sum;
    }
```